Python: How can I parse an XML file to DataFrame with missing child items?
Im trying to parse a SimpleXML file and convert to a dataframe. I have roughly 3000 entries in the xml and one of the child item attributes I need is missing in a few entries. So the dataframe goes off the rails about halfway through (ie columns are off).
Here is a sample of my xml structure:
<ns0:Report_Data xmlns:ns0="workday.data">
    <ns0:Report_Entry>
        <ns0:employeeID>0123456</ns0:employeeID>
        <ns0:sAMAccountName>mo.howard</ns0:sAMAccountName>
        <ns0:userPrincipalName>mo.howard@contoso.com</ns0:userPrincipalName>
        <ns0:country>USA</ns0:country>
        <ns0:company>Contoso</ns0:company>
    </ns0:Report_Entry>
    <ns0:Report_Entry>
        <ns0:employeeID>0123457</ns0:employeeID>
        <ns0:sAMAccountName>larry.fine</ns0:sAMAccountName>
        <ns0:country>Italy</ns0:country>
        <ns0:company>Acme</ns0:company>
    </ns0:Report_Entry>
    <ns0:Report_Entry>
        <ns0:employeeID>0123456</ns0:employeeID>
        <ns0:sAMAccountName>curly.howard</ns0:sAMAccountName>
        <ns0:userPrincipalName>curly.howard@contoso.com</ns0:userPrincipalName>
        <ns0:country>USA</ns0:country>
        <ns0:company>Contoso</ns0:company>
    </ns0:Report_Entry>
    ...
    ...
    ...
</ns0:Report_Data>

Note *** A few entries are missing "ns0:userPrincipalName"
Here is a sample of my code:
   # Parse XML File
wd = open(wdpath + 'wd.xml', 'r')
contents = wd.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'xml')
# Choose appropriate attributes
id = soup.find_all('ns0:employeeID')
email = soup.find_all('ns0:userPrincipalName')
country = soup.find_all('ns0:country')
company = soup.find_all('ns0:company')

data = []
for i in range(0, len(id)):
    rows = [email[i].get_text(), country[i].get_text(), company[i].get_text()]
    data.append(rows)
# Assign Column names to attributes
ri = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Email', 'Country', 'Company'])
ri.to_csv(outpath + 'Report_' + cdt + '.csv', index=False)

*** Here is an example of the output if I iterate for len of email:
csv
*** As you can see, curly.howard's information is incorrect. it continues to write the 'country' and 'company' attributes but misses the 'email, instead of writing "None" which I want.
If i run this as is I get a "IndexError: list index out of range". This is because "range(0, len(id))" has more entries than "email" since email is missing from some. So it appears each column is being created independently.
What I'm hoping to do is iterate each ns0:Report_Entry and if ns0:sAMAccountName is not present, fill it in with "N/A" or the var id or something like that.
Ive tried using "if i is not None, do this" but its not working, or my logic is off.
If anyone has any info it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Given the structure of your XML Report_Entry element, I think you should rather search for the fields without the "ns0" part.
The only way to get a None for any of the variables id, email, country or company is if these subelements are completely absent from the element of type Report_Entry in your xml file, so you should rather read it entry by entry and then create the row you'd be filling to the data frame:
with open("report_entry.xml", "r") as file:
    xml_content = file.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_content, "xml")

# Read xml file one entry at at a time
data: list[list[str | None]] = []

for report_entry in soup.find_all("Report_Entry"):
    employee_id = report_entry.find("employeeID")
    user_principal_name = report_entry.find("userPrincipalName")
    sAMA_account_name = report_entry.find("sAMAccountName")
    country = report_entry.find("country")
    company = report_entry.find("company")

    employee_id = employee_id.get_text()
    user_principal_name = (
        user_principal_name.get_text() if user_principal_name else None
    )
    sAMA_account_name = sAMA_account_name.get_text() if sAMA_account_name else None
    country = country.get_text() if country else None
    company = company.get_text() if company else None

    data += [[employee_id,  user_principal_name, sAMA_account_name, country, company]]

report_entries_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Id", "Email", "Name", "Country", "Company"])

Thus, even if the element userPrincipalName is completely missing from some of the report entries, you would still have a None value for that column for that employee id in your data frame.
Cheers

Thanks for your quick reply!
re: "I think you should rather search for the fields without the "ns0" part"
good idea. Ive updated that.
Unfortunately after updating the rest, I'm still getting the same IndexError: list index out of range.
The issue is that any missing "userPrincipalName" doesn not show up as
"None" in the dataframe. it just completely ignores it. Maybe i need to investigate something other than bs4.
I'll keep trying. thanks!

I already explained what would be the only possible reason that would give you a list index out of range error. It is that the field is missing from every report entry then, and I don't see why you can't just put a None manually when you're filling up the data frame

Because when I run the code snippet I put up there, it works fine when the field is missing, it gets put as None in the data frame

Sorry. Very strange, because when i run your code i get the same "IndexError: list index out of range" unless it has something to do with the way im importing the data?:
wd = open(wdpath + 'wd.xml', 'r').
contents = wd.read().
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'xml').

I told you the only reason to get that error is if the field is gone from all the elements, assuming you are reading the data correctly. Could you provide a simple iteration with your example? Like, not only one entry, but maybe two, from the xml file? Also, you should rather open files in a context manager, I edited my answer to include this as well.

You should at least make sure that you read the data correctly with checking if len(id) is 0

I've edited my original post to the best of my abilities. As you can see the element (including the 'userPrincipalName' Tags) is missing for larry.fine. There are about 5 of these out of 3000. So len of email throws off the rows. len of id gives me that error because there are more id's than email's. I appreciate your help but I do not know of any other way to explain this.

Ok I see what you mean. If i dump the xml directly to csv I DO see blank cells where no elements are found. (doing this: df = pd.read_xml(wdpath + 'wd.xml') |
df.to_csv(wdpath + 'NEW.csv', index=False) This is what I was expecting. Perhaps my issue issue is related to something else.

You should really learn to test your logic with small examples without doing multiple complex tasks in a row on a big file, check the length of stuff found before checking the data frame, then check the data frame, then check the csv... Do you work with notebooks?

Ok the field is completely gone, so your logic to get the elements is off, you can't use "find_all" since you lose the position of the missing fields, I'll update my answer

@JeffJelen Did you manage to fix your code?
